# ASP.NET MVC2 and MemberShipProvider: How well do they go together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I have an existing ASP.NET application with lots of users and a large database. Now I want to have it in MVC 2. I do not want to migrate, I do it more or less from scratch. The database I want to keep and not touch too much.

I already have my database tables and I also want to keep my LINQ to SQL-Layer. I didn't use a MembershipProvider in my current implementation (in ASP.NET 1.0 that wasn't strongly supported).

So, either I write my own Membershipprovider to meet the needs of my database and app or I don't use the membershipprovider at all.

I'd like to understand the consequences if I don't use the membership provider. What is linked to that? I understand that in ASP.NET the Login-Controls are linked to the provider. The AccountModel which is automatically generated with MVC2 could easily be changed to support my existing logic.

What happens when a user is identified by a an AuthCookie? Does MVC use the MembershipProvider then?

Am I overlooking something?
I have the same questions regarding RoleProvider.

Input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With MVC it is simple to bypass the Membership and Role provider framework altogether.  Sometimes it is easier to do this than to implement custom Membership/Role providers, in particular if your authn/authz model doesn't quite fit the mold of those providers.

First, you should realize that you don't need to write everything from scratch, you can use the core Forms authentication API, *which can be used independently* of the Membership/Role provider framework:

- `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` -
  Call this after user has been
  authenticated, specify the user name
- `Request.IsAuthenticated` - Returns
  true if SetAuthCookie was called
- `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` - Returns the user name specified in the call to SetAuthCookie

So here is what you do in MVC to bypass the Membership/Role provider:

1. **Authentication**: In your
   controller, authenticate the user
   using your custom logic.If 
   successful, call
   `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`
   with the user name.
2. **Authorization**: Create a custom
   authorize attribute (deriving from
   AuthorizeAttribute) .  In the
   `AuthorizeCore` override, implement
   your custom authorization logic,
   taking the user in
   `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`
   and the roles defined in the Roles
   property of the AuthorizeAttribute base class. 
   Note you can also define properties on your custom
   authorization attribute and use that in your authorization logic.
   For example you can define a property representing roles as enumerated values
   specific to your app, instead of using the Roles property which is just a string.
3. Affix your controllers and actions with your
   custom authorize attribute,
   instead of the default Authorize
   attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Although you most likely *can* do this without a custom membership provider, I'm not sure that you save that much effort. Until I read [this blog post](http://erictopia.com/2010/05/building-a-mvc2-template-part-8-adding-a-custom-membership-provider/) I thought implementing one was hard, but it's really not. Basically you do this:

1. Create a class that inherits `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider`.
2. `MembershipProvider` is an `abstract` class, so you are readily shown what methods need to be implemented.
3. The names are pretty self explanatory, so you can probably more or less copy your existing logic.

You *might* end up doing more than you need with this approach - but on the other hand, anything you might want to use now or in the future that requires a membership provider will already have its needs met.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the SQLMembershipProvider is available here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx. Take that as a base.

It looks a bit much at first, but you only have to implement the methods you need.

Yes the AuthCookie is used. Yes its a good idea to use the MembershipProvider, because it is well known by other developers.

There are thinks I dont like about it: For example  It is not possible to have a transaction that spans the creation of a user by the membershipsystem and some other data in your own datbase. But still it works well.

Comment: Hm, I still would like to understand from where the MembershipProvider is invoked. In which situations ASP.NET/MVC will use the configured membership provider??? Or is it only used when I am explicitly referring to it like in the AccountModel?

Comment: The Membership provider must be invoked in your code, as you can see in the code generated when you create a new MVC project in VS.  The Role provider OTOH is invoked by the built in Authorize attribute.  You can create a custom Authorize attribute and bypass Membership/Role provider altogether (see my answer).  This is perfectly valid approach if creating a custom Membership/Role provider doesn't fit what you're trying to do.